# How do you get started with AngularStrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm newbie to AngularJS and it's not very clear to me how to get started with [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)? Maybe one comprehensive example of simple page that implements modal example how it references modal controller and mgcrea.ngStrap module?

Comment: they have plunkr's provided in their documentation  - http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals click the little plunkr icon - or  here - http://plnkr.co/edit/xMXhhwl527AJzf8a0jTY?p=preview . that's about as indepth of an explanation as it gets. If you are having trouble, try creating one and *show the code* in a question.

Comment: What!? No way!! Thank a lot I didn't see that icon at all. They should've made it a bit smaller?!!